# Creating VM in Resource Group using Specialized VM but would like to enforce existing user to reset the password while creating vm

Tags: azure

I have below scenario:

1. I have on-premises VHD with Windows Server 2012 R2 installed and ready for Azure environment.
2. Successfully uploaded to Azure Storage.
3. Am able to create VM using Specialized vhd (uploaded vhd) on New /Existing Resource Group.

Questions:

I have one user account (ex:Test) in specialized vhd, this user would like to enforce to password change while creating VM using specilaized vhd on Azure resource group.

Hence request you to share any script or Template would be helpful, also I should be able to read the password and update the same password to other users on the vm.

Let me know if you need any more info on the same.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a vm image, and you have azure Virtual Machine Agent installed on the vhd you uploaded, you can reset password in the azure vm blade under 'Support + Troubleshoot' -> reset password.

now to enforce a password to be set during vm creation you will have to do that with powershell

===========================================

`Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -VMName "myVM" -Name "myVMAccess" -Location WestUS -UserName  $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Username -Password $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password -typeHandlerVersion "2.0"`

=================================================

If you will like to create a deploy script for Azure RM you can copy the azure quick start template https://github.com/Azure/AzureStack-QuickStart-Templates/tree/master/101-simple-windows-vm and customize it to use your image by changing

```
    "imagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "imageOffer": "WindowsServer",
    "OSDiskName": "osdisk",
```

you will also need to change vmadmin1 to your username

```
    "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
        },
        "defaultValue": "vmadmin1"
    },'
```

And more importantly for you specific condition remove the defaultvalue line

```
    "adminPassword": {
        "type": "securestring",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The password "
        }
    }, `
```

Leaving the default value line out will then prompt the user for a password.